# Q_ASSERT(item->d_ptr->scene) in qgraphicsitem.cpp

Tags: c++, qt, assert, qgraphicsitem

I'm getting an assertion when I remove two graphicsitems.
For instance I have a class which inherits QUndoCommand with the following code :

```
void CCommandCreationItem::undo () {
    m_pSynop->removeItem(m_pItem);
}


void CCommandCreationItem::redo() {
    m_pSynop->addItem(m_pItem);
}
```

I'm using QUndoView to visualize the stack. 
So I create 2 items, and I have a stack like this:

```
Initial state
Create (1) 
Create (2) <-
```

When I undo Create(2) **then** Create(1) it works.

```
undo()                    undo()
--------------            -----------------
Initial state             Initial state <-
Create (1) <-             Create (1)
Create (2)                Create (2)
```

but when I'm on Create(2) and I just go on "Initial state" (I suppose it does the two undo() but faster than I) it crashs with the following assertion:

```
Q_ASSERT(item->d_ptr->scene) in qgraphicsitem.cpp
```

I'm using qt4.7.3.

It looks like, it's trying to draw an item which doesn't have a attached scene. [Edit]

Am I doing something wrong ?

Callstack:

```
>   QtCored4.dll!qt_message_output(QtMsgType msgType=QtFatalMsg, const char * buf=0x073f8118)  Line 2270    C++
    QtCored4.dll!qt_message(QtMsgType msgType=QtFatalMsg, const char * msg=0x672aa0d8, char * ap=0x002f9980)  Line 2328 + 0x12 bytes    C++
    QtCored4.dll!qFatal(const char * msg=0x672aa0d8, ...)  Line 2511 + 0xf bytes    C++
    QtCored4.dll!qt_assert(const char * assertion=0x65ad6934, const char * file=0x65ad6914, int line=11230)  Line 2027 + 0x16 bytes C++
    QtGuid4.dll!QGraphicsItemEffectSourcePrivate::draw(QPainter * painter=0x002fa41c)  Line 11230 + 0x29 bytes  C++
    QtGuid4.dll!QGraphicsEffectSource::draw(QPainter * painter=0x002fa41c)  Line 236    C++
    QtGuid4.dll!QGraphicsEffect::drawSource(QPainter * painter=0x002fa41c)  Line 254    C++
    QtGuid4.dll!QGraphicsColorizeEffect::draw(QPainter * painter=0x002fa41c)  Line 692  C++
    QtGuid4.dll!QGraphicsScenePrivate::drawSubtreeRecursive(QGraphicsItem * item=0x06d55ec0, QPainter * painter=0x002fa41c, const QTransform * const viewTransform=0x00000000, QRegion * exposedRegion=0x06d31e98, QWidget * widget=0x06c68a38, double parentOpacity=1.0000000000000000, const QTransform * const effectTransform=0x00000000)  Line 4847    C++
    QtGuid4.dll!QGraphicsScenePrivate::drawItems(QPainter * painter=0x002fa41c, const QTransform * const viewTransform=0x00000000, QRegion * exposedRegion=0x06d31e98, QWidget * widget=0x06c68a38)  Line 4735 + 0x34 bytes C++
    QtGuid4.dll!QGraphicsView::paintEvent(QPaintEvent * event=0x002fad5c)  Line 3470    C++
    QtGuid4.dll!QWidget::event(QEvent * event=0x002fad5c)  Line 8406    C++
    QtGuid4.dll!QFrame::event(QEvent * e=0x002fad5c)  Line 557 + 0xc bytes  C++
    QtGuid4.dll!QAbstractScrollArea::viewportEvent(QEvent * e=0x002fad5c)  Line 1043 + 0xc bytes    C++
    QtGuid4.dll!QGraphicsView::viewportEvent(QEvent * event=0x002fad5c)  Line 2865  C++
    QtGuid4.dll!QAbstractScrollAreaPrivate::viewportEvent(QEvent * event=0x002fad5c)  Line 100 + 0x28 bytes C++
    QtGuid4.dll!QAbstractScrollAreaFilter::eventFilter(QObject * o=0x06c68a38, QEvent * e=0x002fad5c)  Line 116 + 0x29 bytes    C++
    QtCored4.dll!QCoreApplicationPrivate::sendThroughObjectEventFilters(QObject * receiver=0x06c68a38, QEvent * event=0x002fad5c)  Line 846 + 0x15 bytes    C++
    QtGuid4.dll!QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper(QObject * receiver=0x06c68a38, QEvent * e=0x002fad5c)  Line 4458 + 0x11 bytes    C++
    QtGuid4.dll!QApplication::notify(QObject * receiver=0x06c68a38, QEvent * e=0x002fad5c)  Line 4427 + 0x10 bytes  C++
    QtCored4.dll!QCoreApplication::notifyInternal(QObject * receiver=0x06c68a38, QEvent * event=0x002fad5c)  Line 731 + 0x15 bytes  C++
    QtCored4.dll!QCoreApplication::sendSpontaneousEvent(QObject * receiver=0x06c68a38, QEvent * event=0x002fad5c)  Line 218 + 0x38 bytes    C++
    QtGuid4.dll!QWidgetPrivate::drawWidget(QPaintDevice * pdev=0x05a19fa8, const QRegion & rgn={...}, const QPoint & offset={...}, int flags=4, QPainter * sharedPainter=0x00000000, QWidgetBackingStore * backingStore=0x059b5b80)  Line 5492 + 0xe bytes  C++
    QtGuid4.dll!QWidgetPrivate::paintSiblingsRecursive(QPaintDevice * pdev=0x05a19fa8, const QList<QObject *> & siblings={...}, int index=0, const QRegion & rgn={...}, const QPoint & offset={...}, int flags=4, QPainter * sharedPainter=0x00000000, QWidgetBackingStore * backingStore=0x059b5b80)  Line 5700    C++
    QtGuid4.dll!QWidgetPrivate::drawWidget(QPaintDevice * pdev=0x05a19fa8, const QRegion & rgn={...}, const QPoint & offset={...}, int flags=4, QPainter * sharedPainter=0x00000000, QWidgetBackingStore * backingStore=0x059b5b80)  Line 5547  C++
    QtGuid4.dll!QWidgetPrivate::paintSiblingsRecursive(QPaintDevice * pdev=0x05a19fa8, const QList<QObject *> & siblings={...}, int index=2, const QRegion & rgn={...}, const QPoint & offset={...}, int flags=4, QPainter * sharedPainter=0x00000000, QWidgetBackingStore * backingStore=0x059b5b80)  Line 5700    C++
    QtGuid4.dll!QWidgetPrivate::drawWidget(QPaintDevice * pdev=0x05a19fa8, const QRegion & rgn={...}, const QPoint & offset={...}, int flags=4, QPainter * sharedPainter=0x00000000, QWidgetBackingStore * backingStore=0x059b5b80)  Line 5547  C++
    QtGuid4.dll!QWidgetPrivate::paintSiblingsRecursive(QPaintDevice * pdev=0x05a19fa8, const QList<QObject *> & siblings={...}, int index=0, const QRegion & rgn={...}, const QPoint & offset={...}, int flags=4, QPainter * sharedPainter=0x00000000, QWidgetBackingStore * backingStore=0x059b5b80)  Line 5700    C++
    QtGuid4.dll!QWidgetPrivate::drawWidget(QPaintDevice * pdev=0x05a19fa8, const QRegion & rgn={...}, const QPoint & offset={...}, int flags=4, QPainter * sharedPainter=0x00000000, QWidgetBackingStore * backingStore=0x059b5b80)  Line 5547  C++
    QtGuid4.dll!QWidgetPrivate::paintSiblingsRecursive(QPaintDevice * pdev=0x05a19fa8, const QList<QObject *> & siblings={...}, int index=1, const QRegion & rgn={...}, const QPoint & offset={...}, int flags=4, QPainter * sharedPainter=0x00000000, QWidgetBackingStore * backingStore=0x059b5b80)  Line 5700    C++
    QtGuid4.dll!QWidgetPrivate::drawWidget(QPaintDevice * pdev=0x05a19fa8, const QRegion & rgn={...}, const QPoint & offset={...}, int flags=4, QPainter * sharedPainter=0x00000000, QWidgetBackingStore * backingStore=0x059b5b80)  Line 5547  C++
    QtGuid4.dll!QWidgetPrivate::paintSiblingsRecursive(QPaintDevice * pdev=0x05a19fa8, const QList<QObject *> & siblings={...}, int index=0, const QRegion & rgn={...}, const QPoint & offset={...}, int flags=4, QPainter * sharedPainter=0x00000000, QWidgetBackingStore * backingStore=0x059b5b80)  Line 5700    C++
    QtGuid4.dll!QWidgetPrivate::drawWidget(QPaintDevice * pdev=0x05a19fa8, const QRegion & rgn={...}, const QPoint & offset={...}, int flags=4, QPainter * sharedPainter=0x00000000, QWidgetBackingStore * backingStore=0x059b5b80)  Line 5547  C++
    QtGuid4.dll!QWidgetPrivate::paintSiblingsRecursive(QPaintDevice * pdev=0x05a19fa8, const QList<QObject *> & siblings={...}, int index=43, const QRegion & rgn={...}, const QPoint & offset={...}, int flags=4, QPainter * sharedPainter=0x00000000, QWidgetBackingStore * backingStore=0x059b5b80)  Line 5700   C++
    QtGuid4.dll!QWidgetPrivate::paintSiblingsRecursive(QPaintDevice * pdev=0x05a19fa8, const QList<QObject *> & siblings={...}, int index=45, const QRegion & rgn={...}, const QPoint & offset={...}, int flags=4, QPainter * sharedPainter=0x00000000, QWidgetBackingStore * backingStore=0x059b5b80)  Line 5687   C++
    QtGuid4.dll!QWidgetPrivate::paintSiblingsRecursive(QPaintDevice * pdev=0x05a19fa8, const QList<QObject *> & siblings={...}, int index=46, const QRegion & rgn={...}, const QPoint & offset={...}, int flags=4, QPainter * sharedPainter=0x00000000, QWidgetBackingStore * backingStore=0x059b5b80)  Line 5687   C++
    QtGuid4.dll!QWidgetPrivate::paintSiblingsRecursive(QPaintDevice * pdev=0x05a19fa8, const QList<QObject *> & siblings={...}, int index=48, const QRegion & rgn={...}, const QPoint & offset={...}, int flags=4, QPainter * sharedPainter=0x00000000, QWidgetBackingStore * backingStore=0x059b5b80)  Line 5687   C++
    QtGuid4.dll!QWidgetPrivate::paintSiblingsRecursive(QPaintDevice * pdev=0x05a19fa8, const QList<QObject *> & siblings={...}, int index=49, const QRegion & rgn={...}, const QPoint & offset={...}, int flags=4, QPainter * sharedPainter=0x00000000, QWidgetBackingStore * backingStore=0x059b5b80)  Line 5687   C++
    QtGuid4.dll!QWidgetPrivate::paintSiblingsRecursive(QPaintDevice * pdev=0x05a19fa8, const QList<QObject *> & siblings={...}, int index=50, const QRegion & rgn={...}, const QPoint & offset={...}, int flags=4, QPainter * sharedPainter=0x00000000, QWidgetBackingStore * backingStore=0x059b5b80)  Line 5687   C++
    QtGuid4.dll!QWidgetPrivate::paintSiblingsRecursive(QPaintDevice * pdev=0x05a19fa8, const QList<QObject *> & siblings={...}, int index=51, const QRegion & rgn={...}, const QPoint & offset={...}, int flags=4, QPainter * sharedPainter=0x00000000, QWidgetBackingStore * backingStore=0x059b5b80)  Line 5687   C++
    QtGuid4.dll!QWidgetPrivate::drawWidget(QPaintDevice * pdev=0x05a19fa8, const QRegion & rgn={...}, const QPoint & offset={...}, int flags=5, QPainter * sharedPainter=0x00000000, QWidgetBackingStore * backingStore=0x059b5b80)  Line 5547  C++
    QtGuid4.dll!QWidgetBackingStore::sync()  Line 1336  C++
    QtGuid4.dll!QWidgetPrivate::syncBackingStore()  Line 1845   C++
    QtGuid4.dll!QWidget::event(QEvent * event=0x073e3b28)  Line 8553    C++
    QtGuid4.dll!QMainWindow::event(QEvent * event=0x073e3b28)  Line 1481    C++
    QtGuid4.dll!QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper(QObject * receiver=0x002ffa30, QEvent * e=0x073e3b28)  Line 4462 + 0x11 bytes    C++
    QtGuid4.dll!QApplication::notify(QObject * receiver=0x002ffa30, QEvent * e=0x073e3b28)  Line 4427 + 0x10 bytes  C++
    QtCored4.dll!QCoreApplication::notifyInternal(QObject * receiver=0x002ffa30, QEvent * event=0x073e3b28)  Line 731 + 0x15 bytes  C++
    QtCored4.dll!QCoreApplication::sendEvent(QObject * receiver=0x002ffa30, QEvent * event=0x073e3b28)  Line 215 + 0x39 bytes   C++
    QtCored4.dll!QCoreApplicationPrivate::sendPostedEvents(QObject * receiver=0x002ffa30, int event_type=77, QThreadData * data=0x00df3300)  Line 1372 + 0xd bytes  C++
    QtCored4.dll!QCoreApplication::sendPostedEvents(QObject * receiver=0x002ffa30, int event_type=77)  Line 1265 + 0x11 bytes   C++
    QtGuid4.dll!QGraphicsViewPrivate::dispatchPendingUpdateRequests()  Line 189 + 0x17 bytes    C++
    QtGuid4.dll!QGraphicsScenePrivate::_q_processDirtyItems()  Line 510 + 0x20 bytes    C++
    QtGuid4.dll!QGraphicsScene::qt_metacall(QMetaObject::Call _c=InvokeMetaMethod, int _id=14, void * * _a=0x00e265f0)  Line 130 + 0x12 bytes   C++
    EditeurSynop.exe!CSynoptiqueEditeur::qt_metacall(QMetaObject::Call _c=InvokeMetaMethod, int _id=18, void * * _a=0x00e265f0)  Line 88 + 0x17 bytes   C++
    QtCored4.dll!QMetaObject::metacall(QObject * object=0x05ab0860, QMetaObject::Call cl=InvokeMetaMethod, int idx=18, void * * argv=0x00e265f0)  Line 238  C++
    QtCored4.dll!QMetaCallEvent::placeMetaCall(QObject * object=0x05ab0860)  Line 535 + 0x19 bytes  C++
    QtCored4.dll!QObject::event(QEvent * e=0x073d8070)  Line 1217 + 0x14 bytes  C++
    QtGuid4.dll!QGraphicsScene::event(QEvent * event=0x073d8070)  Line 3544 + 0x10 bytes    C++
    QtGuid4.dll!QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper(QObject * receiver=0x05ab0860, QEvent * e=0x073d8070)  Line 4462 + 0x11 bytes    C++
    QtGuid4.dll!QApplication::notify(QObject * receiver=0x05ab0860, QEvent * e=0x073d8070)  Line 3862 + 0x10 bytes  C++
    QtCored4.dll!QCoreApplication::notifyInternal(QObject * receiver=0x05ab0860, QEvent * event=0x073d8070)  Line 731 + 0x15 bytes  C++
    QtCored4.dll!QCoreApplication::sendEvent(QObject * receiver=0x05ab0860, QEvent * event=0x073d8070)  Line 215 + 0x39 bytes   C++
    QtCored4.dll!QCoreApplicationPrivate::sendPostedEvents(QObject * receiver=0x00000000, int event_type=0, QThreadData * data=0x00df3300)  Line 1372 + 0xd bytes   C++
    QtCored4.dll!qt_internal_proc(HWND__ * hwnd=0x003f0a28, unsigned int message=1025, unsigned int wp=0, long lp=0)  Line 497 + 0x10 bytes C++
```

Just added a trace

```
void CCommandCreationItem::undo () {
    m_pSynop->removeItem(m_pItem);
    qDebug() << "@ITEM : " << reinterpret_cast<int*>(m_pItem);
}

@ITEM :  0x71b5e40 
@ITEM :  0x6a65018 
ASSERT: "item->d_ptr->scene" in file graphicsview\qgraphicsitem.cpp, line 11230
```

For visual : https://i.stack.imgur.com/grhWw.png

EDIT: It seems that this assert just appear when I have a precise configuration but I can't figure out which one ..

Do you know in which cases this assert appears ?

Comment: attach call stack of when assertion fails.

Comment: What if you do the following experiment: call two times in a row this line of code `m_pSynop->removeItem(m_pItem);`. I ask, because you always remove the same item from the same view when undo.

Comment: @vahancho I forgot to mention what is was 2 distinct instances of CCommandCreationItem with 2 different item.

Comment: @Endo, can you check whether undoing to the initial state removes different items and not the same twice? I think, that could be the root cause.

Comment: I'm suspecting some memory issue, run it with valgrind with memory check or some other tool.